# Avoid Jasper Studio adding timestamp comment in jrxml file

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

In Jasper Studio 6.1.1 final each time you save a report file a timestamp comment is added to the jrxml file like this:

```
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2016-07-22T15:29:22 -->
```

This behaviour is annoying when you use a version system like SVN or Git because it marks the file as pending of commit for no reason (if no real changes were done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu `Windows` -> `Preferences` -> `Jaspersoft Studio`: uncheck the option `Add timestamp information when saving the JRXML file`.

On newer versions of Jaspersoft Studio you may need to click on `Compatibility` option after the `Jaspersoft Studio` option (I can't test this by now).